# Python as back-end and Polymer as the front-end

Tags: python, polymer, desktop-application

I want to create a desktop application written in python and using polymer as the front-end. To access the user interface, we use web browser such as chrome, mozilla, and safari. I did a lot of research in how to do this. The only reference I have is home Assistant, but I'm still don't quite understand about the architecture and the approach. Anyone have another solution or approach in how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python ships with a basic http server, however according to the docs it's not made for production use. But it's probably good enough for your use case (single user). On top of this you can implement a basic REST-Api and serve your frontend (.js/.html) as static content.

Or use a framework like django https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: Thanks @Marc Ströbel, I mean the application that i want to build is self hosted, it does not online, it is run locally on a single computer.

Comment: you'll need some kind of http server if you want to use a browser client

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marc Ströbel, I really appreciate that.

Comment: https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/convert-django-website-to-a-progressive-web-app-3536bc4f2862